# Are Variables Initialized inside Function Declaration Always Re-initialized When The Function Execute (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, variables, scope

My question is based on two premises: (1) codes are not executed until the function containing them is called and (2) variables are saved in memory.

So, are variables initialized inside function declaration always re-initialized when the function execute?

To demonstrate, if I initialize a variable inside function declaration to a huge object and call that function, then, the huge object will be created, saved, or and processed in memory. If I call or execute that function many times, then the huge object will be created, saved, or and processed everytime the function executes. Then, there will be so many and big processing of that variable (containing that huge object, and if only one). Therefore, this behavior will result in bad effect for performance. I do not know much about this, is this correct?

This is to demonstrate with code:
If I declare global variables, then the process only involve value-changing. But, if I declare local variable like this:

```
var hugeObj = {
   prop1 : function() {...},
   prop2 : [...],
   prop3 : {...},
};
```

and I execute the containing function five times, then there will be five "hugeObj" (with different contexts) in memory (and involve more processing).

Can you explain how variables are processed inside function declarations, and will them be created in every execution context?

Comment: Every time you enter that function, if the contents generated within that function are stored within a variable stored elsewhere then it will be repeated for however many times that function is called.

Comment: If you wonder about performance, there's a simple thing you can do to answer your questions: measure.

Comment: Logically, local variables have to be re-initialised each time a function is invoked, otherwise the function would not be guaranteed to produce the same output for any given input.

Comment: @JordanLowe You mean, this is the case when variables are initialized outside functions? Then the only involved process is changing value of those variables?

Bergi Can you make a reliable jsperf test for me regarding this?

Comment: @Bergi Can you make a reliable jsperf test for me regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, each time the function is run it's internal variables are re-initialized and are not reused.

```js
function MyFunc(newValue){
  var v;
  if(newValue) v = newValue;
  return v;
};


console.log(MyFunc()); // undefined
console.log(MyFunc(5)); // 5
console.log(MyFunc()); // undefined

// Therefore we can conclude that the object is re-initialized each time the function is run and its previous variable values are not reused.
```

If you would like it to **not** initialize the variable each time, just initialize the variable globally.

```js
var v;
function MyFunc(newValue){
  if(newValue) v = newValue;
  return v;
};


console.log(MyFunc()); // undefined
console.log(MyFunc(5)); // 5
console.log(MyFunc()); // 5
```

Comment: So, the latter only involves value-changing process, and not re-saving the same variables (of different contexts), and thus more performant?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of [@DustinPoissant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271233/5035890), you can declare different scope (local or global) inside a function.

Let's use the same code as the answer:

```js
function MyFunc(newValue){
  var v;
  if(newValue) v = newValue;
  return v;
};


console.log(MyFunc()); // undefined
console.log(MyFunc(5)); // 5
console.log(MyFunc()); // undefined
```

In this case the scope is the local function, but if you remvoe `var` keyword, your scope changes to global (yes, `v` variable will be attached to `window` object):

```js
function MyFunc(newValue){
  if(newValue) v = newValue;
  return v;
};


console.log(MyFunc()); // undefined
console.log(MyFunc(5)); // 5
console.log(MyFunc()); // 5
```

That's the same as write:

```js
function MyFunc(newValue){
  if(newValue) window.v = newValue;
  return window.v;
};


console.log(MyFunc()); // undefined
console.log(MyFunc(5)); // 5
console.log(MyFunc()); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Because one of the variables is stored externally, run both, one will maintain its values, the one with the variable initialised within the function is overwritten.

```js
var array = ["1","2","3","4","5"];

function MyFunc()
{
  var current = "0";
  console.log("Iteration");
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
    current += array[i];
    console.log(current);
  }
};

console.log(MyFunc());
console.log(MyFunc());
```

```js
var array = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
var current = "0";

function MyFunc()
{
  console.log("Iteration");
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
    current += array[i];
    console.log(current);
  }
};

console.log(MyFunc());
console.log(MyFunc());
```

Answer (score -1):

Variables are named memory, it all depend on the scope of the variable(Local or Global) Variables inside a functions are called local variables, every time this function is called the variables are re initialized, which means at every call to the function the value of the variable is expected to change.

```
public void myFunction(int val1, String val2)
{
 int a = val1;
 String b = val2;
 System.out.println(val2 +" "+val1);
}
```

a and b in the above are local variable that will be affected base on the parameters passed to it by the method/function calls
so the value of a variables in a function will always change

Comment: Please don't post Java code to a JavaScript question :-)

Comment: That's not javascript

Comment: So sorry, I feel its a general question on programming, I dont know he was specific about the language

Comment: While this answer is wrong, it is still an attempted answer. This should not be [recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11189296). See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)